# How to set a different parameter to sort by in Angular2 during runtime

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I'm using ng2-order-pipe from here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-order-pipe

And I want to be able to switch the order by parameter from string a to string b when a user clicks a button.

So far I've tried setting the order by to a value of the class like so:

```
export class CompanyPage ...{
parameterName:string = 'location';
}
```

and in HTML :

```
<div *ngFor="let job of jobsList | orderBy: parameterName> ...
```

The on click method:

```
this.parameterName = newValue;
```

This method does sort by the parameter set on the start but does not update when the user clicks the button, is it possible to accomplish this in other ways?

Job class:

```
class jobInfo {
    id: number
    jobTitle: string
    description: string
    created: Date
    companyName: string
    logoUrl: string
    location: string
    minSalary: number
    maxSalary: number
    requirements: string
    benefits: string
}
```

The newValue is from here:

```
(change)="onDisplayChanged($event.target.value)
```

Again, I've debugged this far, the click method does its job and the parameterName gets the value I wanted it to get.  It just doesn't apply it for the pipe (If I change the initial value of it, it will sort differently)

I haven't had time to use plunkr before so I ended up taking a while and changing the code from its origin and turns out it works when I use an orderBy pipe from here instead of the angular2-orderby-pipe module:

https://plnkr.co/edit/8hf3Yor6WCbE0g873EiE?p=preview

Comment: can you show how you assign your `click` method in your code?

Comment: I've debugged the code. The click method does execute and it does change the value of this.parameterName.

Comment: Can you share the class for job and also the value of newValue in your click method?

Comment: If you posted a complete minimal example as a plunkr, we could debug, too, and find where the problem is.